# Using Python for analyzing shapefiles with igraph

Tags: python, gis, igraph, shapefile

I have some experience using networkX when analyzing data from .shp files. I am looking to optimize for speed when performing shortest path analysis and came across igraph. Networkx has/had `read_shp("somefile.shp")` function for passing in .shp file. Is there an analog in igraph for reading in .shp files and creating graphs?

Comment: try this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113799/how-to-read-a-shapefile-in-python/113808

Comment: @TamilSelvan the question is about getting the .shp file into igraph for analysis as a graph object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not (as of version 0.9.8), but you can convert a networkx graph to igraph format and then use igraph's fast analysis methods on it.

https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph.Graph.html#from_networkx